# Superset SqlAlchemy-Trino ERROR: Unexpected database format catalog/hive/

Tags: sqlalchemy, apache-superset, trino

I'm trying to create database connection from Superset to Trino.

What I've done:

1. Run "echo "sqlalchemy-trino" >> ./docker/requirements-local.txt" from my superset root folder to add trino database driver to superset.
2. Modify "docker-compose-non-dev.yml" to load docker/docker-bootstrap.sh as mentioned by @dungdm93 in https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/13640
3. Run "docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up" to start superset docker
4. Login to superset
5. And then I tried to add database connection to Trino using the following connection string "trino://my_username:my_password@trino_coordinator_ip:8090/catalog/hive/"
6. Click "Test Connection" button.

Expected result:
Able to add database connection to Trino and able to query Trino from superset.

Actual result:
I got the following error message "ERROR: Unexpected database format catalog/hive/"

Btw, previously I've created external tables in hive that reference to delta table manifest. And Trino is used to access those hive table.

Comment: I think the right  format is ""trino://my_username:my_password@trino_coordinator_ip:8090/hive/""

Comment: Hi @BetoDealmeida, I tried the connection string that you suggested and still wasn't successful.

Btw I was somehow able to connect with this connection string --> presto://trino_coordinator_ip:8090/hive.

Thank you anyway for the respond.